# Oracle Cloud how to assign IPv6 prefix >64 to instance and delegate

Tags: ipv6, oracle-cloud

I am able to assign a /64 prefix to an instance in Oracle cloud but I want to have it act as a router; Delegating and routing a larger subnet to wireguard peers.

This is using Oracle owned IPv6 addresses. I'd expect to be able to assign a /58 out of the /56 they give me to the instance.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Although the VCN has a /56 prefix, every subnet in the VCN must have a /64 prefix (it can be longer if you use BYOIP, but cannot be shorter).

Comment: Can I assign the whole /64 to the instance? And have it route say a /68?

Comment: I have never tried it, so I can only guess, but my guess is no. You can't assign a network to the instance on the GUI, and while nothing prevents you from configuring it from within the instance, my guess is that the cloud router will ignore RAs originating from your VM.